# Using @FindBy to find WebElementS

Tags: java, selenium

We have a list of elements specified by "//input[contains(@name,'smcNetwork')]".
I am used to finding a webelement like

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//*[id='myId']")  private WebElement myelement;
```

But, as per subject the xpath I mentioned returns an array (or list I guess) where I would do

```
List<WebElement> networks = driver.findElementsBy( xpath = "//input[contains(@name,'smcNetwork')]")
```

I would like to do this in a FindBy but it did not seem to work:

```
@FindBy( xpath = "//input[contains(@name,'smcNetwork')]") private List<WebElement> networks;
```

but that was returning null.  Can you do this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = "yourpath")})
public List<WebElement> networks;
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate web element using `@FindBy`, you can use below snippet

```
@FindBy(xpath = "xpathValue")
private static WebElement xpathName;
```

here, you can change access level by making it as public or private/protected.

If you are making it as private then use this locator within that class and define a common method as public.